# How to install Tensorflow with GPU support on MacOSX El Capitain?

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow

I recently started using `keras v2.1.2` with `tensorflow v1.4.0` and have been reading the computational acceleration using GPUs.  I have a NVIDIA graphics card and would like to configure my `tensorflow` and `keras` to utilize this.  It seems that I need to install a separate version of `tensorflow` so instead of breaking my current environment, I am creating another `conda` environment with `conda create -n tensorflow python=3`.

My computer specs are below:

[image]

I noticed a `conda` installation but it's only for `linux` and `windows`.

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu

I read on the `tensorflow` website that they no longer provide GPU support for macOS.

> Note: As of version 1.2, TensorFlow no longer provides GPU support on
>   macOS.
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac

**My question is whether or not it is impossible to utilize GPU support with my current set up?  If so, how can I do this and set it up in my `tensorflow` `conda` environment**?  Will this work for `tensorflow v1.4.0`.  If it is very complicated, please link to a tutorial that will work for these specs.  I've tried a few but could not get any of them to work.

Comment: Have you tried: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow-gpu ?

Comment: I think it might only be for linux from the filenames

Comment: It's not for linux exclusively; I've installed it on Mac using `pip`...

Comment: Which python, osx, and tensorflow versions are you using?  Did you have to configure any cuda stuff separately?